Can't send email in PHP with mail() when it contains "á" "é" characters
I have this weird error where if I paste in a string that contains "á" and "é" (in any part of the string) to the HTML of the email, it won't send the email. There might be other character combos, that's what I found flawy. It looks like this:
$name = "áé";
$email = "something@gmail.com";

$htmlContent = '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="hu">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
                <h3>Dear ' . $name. '!</h3> //error if $name contains both "á" and "é", otherwise email is sent
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ... \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ... \r\n";


if (mail($email, $subject, $htmlContent, $headers))

I tried strval() and mb_encode_mimeheader(), now I'll try replacing "á" and "é" if $name contains it, but that's not too dynamic and perfecct solution.

phpmailer is a mailer library, which you are not using here - so that tag isn't appropriate. (You should probably be using that library though, to make your live easier.)

"it won't send the email" - how did you determine that it did not sent it? (Just because the recipient doesn't receive it, does not necessarily mean that sending failed!)

Is your script file that contains this code saved in UTF-8 encoding to begin with?

Sending emails using the mail() function that contains special characters like "á" and "é", you need to ensure proper encoding of both the email headers and the email body. This usually involves using UTF-8 encoding for both
